# How do I cite this record from the Arolsen Archives?

Tags: citation, archives

The [Help page of the Arolsen Archives](https://collections.arolsen-archives.org/en/help/) includes information about how to cite their records:

> When you cite documents, always give the following information:
>
> [Title of the document], [Sub-collection number]/[Doc-ID]/ITS Digital
>   Archive, Arolsen Archives
>
> Example: Report on Conferences on Unaccompanied Children, 1946,
>   6.1.2/82489042/ITS Digital Archive, Arolsen Archives

However, I'm having a hard time figuring out what the "title of the document" actually is, or where to look for the "sub-collection number".

The record in question is a passenger manifest showing my father-in-law's brother (and FIL as sponsor/destination), which the search engine will only cough up if I look for the mistranscription that's in their index: https://collections.arolsen-archives.org/en/archive/81740087/?p=1&s=Szent-Gyogyi%20Gyula&doc_id=81740087

I see from the URL that the "doc-ID" must be the (unselectable) number that's between the image and the thumbnails (81740087), leaving the thing labeled "Reference Code" (1384075) as the only other number on the page. Is that somehow the "sub-collection number"? And is the title *"Correspondence and nominal roles, done at Belgrad: transport by airplane (MIGEN H-12892); transit countries and final destinations: USA"*, or is it *"Registrations and Files of Displaced Persons, Children and Missing Persons"*, or something else?

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me that the sub-collection number is `3.1.3` (Emigrations), based on the fact that the example shows three dot-separated numbers. However, upon scrolling up on the list, it seems to be `3.1.3.2` (Passenger lists and further compilations on emigrated persons)

The document ID is the Reference Code `81740087` as the help page states:

> When you open the document, you will find the number at the bottom right.

The title should be as shown on the page in the heading: "Correspondence and nominal roles, done at Belgrad: transport by airplane (MIGEN H-12892); transit countries and final destinations: USA"

Which would make your reference:

`Correspondence and nominal roles, done at Belgrad: transport by airplane (MIGEN H-12892); transit countries and final destinations: USA, 3.1.3.2/81740087/ITS Digital Archive, Arolsen Archives`

Comment: I don't see how the reference number could possibly be the document ID; the other number is the one in the URL, twice, with the second occurrence actually _labeled_ "doc_ID".

Comment: And yep: if you open the link (https://collections.arolsen-archives.org/en/archive/3-1-3-2_1384075/?p=1&doc_id=81740087) in a new tab, it puts the image in an overlay window, with a number in the bottom right corner: 81740087, the "doc_ID" from the URL. So that's definitely the number that the help page is talking about.

Comment: You're right, it's talking about the number in the bottom right when the document is open, which is indeed `81740087`. I will amend my answer